# wrote a code in c#. tried to calculate the sum of a list in a recursively but had an error of "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException"

Tags: c#

here is my code: (this is a function)
please help me as soon as possible to solve this problem!

```
    public static int sumlist(List<int> L,Node<int>p1)
    {

        int sum = 0;
        p1 = L.GetFirst();
        if (p1 == null)
            return sum;
        else
        {
            sum = sum + p1.GetInfo();
            p1 = p1.GetNext();
            return sumlist(L,p1);
        }            
    }
```

In the `main` I created a list and a node and "sent" them to the function.

Comment: what does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: How does your `GetFirst` method look like?

Comment: it means that you have error in your recursive call that causes stackoverflow (out of memory)

Comment: @lampi - have you looked at the documentation for StackOverflowException? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Basically, it means you have an infinite recursion. And it occurs because you don't use your `p1` parameter.

Comment: what do you mean I don't use my p1 parameter?

Comment: The way you wrote this it will keep adding the first element in the list to the value 0 forever.

Comment: Something here is totally wrong. What is the method GetFirst on a `List<int>`?

Comment: public Node<T> GetFirst()
        {
            return this.first;
        }

Comment: Please provide the code for the Node class and how do you initialize the List passed to this method

Comment: @lampi, please look at how you could imporove your questions.  We'got some suggestions on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and even [how to ask homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/94928).  See if reading those can help you improve your original question.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that every time you call a function, you push a new entry onto your program's call stack. Every time a function returns, that entry is popped from the stack. The program starts when your main method is pushed onto the stack, and ends when the stack is empty. Also remember that *the call stack has a limited/fixed size*. If you have too many function calls without ever returning, you can **overflow** the stack... hence a StackOverflowException.

Now let's look at your code. In your `sumList()` function, you recursively call the function like this:

```
return sumlist(L,p1);
```

It's using the same `L` list variable, and a `p1` variable that is presumably for holding the current state. However, earlier in the function, you completely throw away whatever value `p1` might happen to contain, without ever using the information:

```
p1 = L.GetFirst();
```

This means you start the list over for every recursive call. You have the same list, and the same intermediate state. Nothing every changes. The result is that you keep calling `sumList()`, and each time getting one more entry deeper into the call stack, until it finally overflows.

Beyond that, your `L` variable only contains `int` values. If you really wanted to sum a `List<int>`, all you'd have to do is say `return L.Sum();`. It seems like what you really want is a `List<Node<int>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You constantly set the node to the first List element, so the function will continue to call itself,  causing a stackexception. Use something like :

```
int sumList(List<int> list)
{
  int sum = 0;
  foreach(int value in list)
     sum += value;
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: The problem i think is with this line: //p1 = L.GetFirst();//!!!